# Linux experiments - amount of files increasing while issuing the command

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system

So when I run this command multiple times (in order to see how many files there are):

```
ls / -R | wc -l &
```

I get the following output:

```
410121
410744
411359
411982
412605
413220
```

It seems like the amount of files is increasing with every command fired. If I wait some time between issuing the commands the amount of files outputted stays the same.

Can anyone explain why is the amount of files growing if there are several commands fired one after another? Is it due to caching?

I'm running a virtual machine with CentOS 7 with 8GB RAM allocated on Win7 host PC.

Comment: It probably has to do with kind-of-files in `/proc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fedorqui rightly pointed out, this is due to the virtual file system /proc (pseudo file system). Your command doesn't guarantee a fixed output since you are checking for list of objects from a folder which implicitly checks in a pseudo file system that creates directories and files for each and every command / process that runs. The results will be even more confusing since the process ids are reused once it reaches the maximum limit.

Comment: does it create a pseudo file for every command including every pipe in a `command1 | command2` expression?

Comment: proc holds a directory for each process id. I think "yes" in this case, since the piped commands will be multiple processes.